# Is this memtest86 error definitely faulty RAM?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I am about to request a warranty exchange for a RAM module that has memtest86 errors. The memtest86 errors are attached.

Before I'd do that I'd like to ask, is this definitely an error with my RAM module or is it possible that I have a CPU/MOBO problem that somehow creates these errors?

[image]

Comment: I would say yes, you have bad memory

Comment: There isn't any great way to tell for certain that it is the RAM module rather than CPU/Mobo, since all three components are required to execute the tests, other than to reproduce the failures in another box (which is often difficult for normal people). I'd say if you have reseated the RAM a couple times, and get repeatable results, return the RAM. Memtest tries very hard to minimize the dependency on other components, though there's only so much software can do on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Memory testing programs, like memtest86, are very useful software tools.  Unfortunately, their results are not always absolutely correct.

Their results can be skewed by other factors, such as a faulty memory controller or CPU.  However, if you did not have any issues before purchasing the memory, this is not likely the case.  Additionally, the software itself is written by humans, which can make errors.  Granted memtest86 has been around a very long time and likely the bugs have been removed.

If you have another computer to test the memory in, then that would be something to try.  However, as stated previously, if you are simply upgrading and had no issues before, the memory is likely bad.

Comment: I haven't changed the computer in a long time, I have just suddenly been getting BSOD errors and decided to run this test. Given this, what is your subjective probability (50%? 90%?) that it's my RAM that's faulty and not my CPU/motherboard ? This will help me to make decisions about what to do

Comment: @BSOD Just from personal experience, it is *most* likely the RAM.